# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 when deploying Angular/Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, heroku, syntax-error

Trying to deploy an Angular/Rails app to heroku.  Did the walkthroughs with heroku, addressed a couple of errors that heroku threw, and I thought things were going to work.

However, when I visit [my frontend page](https://protected-retreat-87097.herokuapp.com/) on my desktop I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` in chrome dev tools console.  When I visit the backend I get `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.`  Heroku logs say nothing about errors, failures, or anything really.  But when I visit the frontend on my laptop the page loads and I'm able to log in.  And when I create a marker, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`, but at a different location than the error I mentioned above.  In addition, when I view the Sources on Chrome dev tools, I don't see all of my html pages.

Here's the code where it's throwing an error on my desktop:

```
(function(){
app.controller('mainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'NgMap', 'CreateMarker'];

function mainController($scope, $http, $state, NgMap, createMarker) {
 debugger;
 var self = this;
 // ###### error on JSON.parse below ##############
 self.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
 // self.currentUser =
 self.newPassword = {};
```

Here's the code where it's throwing an error on my laptop, after I'm logged in and try to create a marker:

```
app.service('CreateMarker', ['$http', function($http) {
 this.createMarker = function(marker) {
 let self = this;
 // ###### error on JSON.parse below ##############
 self.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Comment: Have you looked at what `localStorage.getItem('user')` returns?

Comment: could you briefly post what `localStorage.getItem('user')` is expected to look like? I expect it not to be parsable JSON which would clarify throwing that error. Not throwing any errors in the console when checking over here.

Comment: @muistooshort @thibmaek `localStorage.getItem('user')` returns an object, `{token: "undefined", user: "undefined"}`.  It was working yesterday, so I reverted every commit I made today, but that didn't fix it.  So strange....  localStorage is a parsable JSON.

Comment: If `localStorage.getItem('user')` is return an object then why are you trying to `JSON.parse` it? There might be a problem elsewhere as well, I'd expect those `"undefined"`s to be plain `null`s, perhaps there is some stray stringification going on.

Comment: @JasonFry Your comment is confusing. `localStorage.getItem` will always return a String (or `null`). You say it returns an object, and I'm guessing you mean "JSON object," since you later say it's "a parsable JSON," but the "object" you've given (`{token: ...}`) is not valid JSON (the property names aren't quoted). What is the *actual* String returned by `getItem`?

Comment: @muistooshort @jordan you are both right, I misspoke.  `localStorage.getItem('user')` returns a string.  But I found out the real issue; JSON.parse is asynchronous, but I wasn't accounting for that.  Moving it into a promise chain has solved the issue.  Thanks for lending an ear and being patient with me :)

Comment: Never mind, I just found out that `JSON.parse` is synchronous.  Still at a loss for the cause of the error, though I was able to remove most `JSON.parse`s as extraneous in my code.

Comment: So it is still broken? Are you sure you don't have a bunch of garbage stuck in local storage?